# how to pass array to constructor in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor

I am trying to pass an array to constructor in C++ but it is not working:

```
arrayClass(int *array,int size){
        a = new int[15];
        for(int i(0); i < size; i++) {
           this->a[i] = array[i];
        }
        this->size = size;
cout << "In second constructor" << endl;
    }
```

in main()

```
int array[3]={1,2,3};
arrayClass a2(array,3);
```

Comment: Please make your question less vague. "Not working" can mean many things. Do you get errors? Which ones? Can you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: you pass in an array and its length, but in the constructor you copy it to an array of fixed size (`15`), or possibly uninitialized? If `a` and `this->a` are the same data, you will have troubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is working fine - just take care to `delete[]` with `new[]` allocated space accordingly after you're finished (to prevent memory leaking). Also instead of using 15 as hardcoded constant, you probably want to use the parameter `size` (otherwise for arrays bigger than 15 elements, you would have an memory access violation).

```
class ArrayClass{
public:
  ArrayClass(int* array, int size){
    a = new int[size];
    for (int i(0); i < size; i++) {
      this->a[i] = array[i];
    }
    this->size = size;
  }
  virtual ~ArrayClass(){
    delete[] a;
  }
private:
  int* a;
  int size;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  int array[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
  ArrayClass a2(array, 3);
  return 0;
}
```

Arrays can be allocated in C++ in different ways:

```
int a[3]; // will allocate the space for 3 elements statically from the stack

int* a = new int[3]; // will allocate space for 3 elements dynamically from the heap
```

Basically it decides in which memory your array will be located - but there are many differences in these two methods involved - see i.e. [What and where are the stack and heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap).
Some main differences are:

- stack allocations can't use a dynamical length like a variable i.e. `int size = 10; int a[size]; // <- is invalid`
- stack allocations are 'deleted' automatically when they are out-of-scope
- heap allocations have to be `deleted[]` explicit to not leak memory

The line `int* a = new int[3];` will declare a pointer-variable to an memory location where 3 `int` values can fit in. So after the declaration these 3 values can be addressed directly as `a[0]`, `a[1]` and `a[2]`. After all operations are finished `delete[] a;` is necessary. Because if the pointer `a*` is getting out-of-scope (i.e. end of your function) the memory for the 3 values is not deallocated automatically.

Comment: Constantin: Thank you very much.But I have a doubt could you explain difference between int *a vs int* a.Is int* represent array of pointers?

Comment: @user2895589 I have edited my answer and explained the `int* a = new int[size];` more in detail. Hopefully it's helpful for you!